# unqiueidenfitier is not compatible with type int SQL Server Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012-express

I have the following procedure for inserting into a user table:

```
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Procedure (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the procedure.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Andy Armstrong
-- Create date: 
-- Description: 
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE db_SignupAddLogin 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @LoginName VARCHAR(15), 
    @LoginPassword VARCHAR(15)


AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @GUID = NEWID();
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
     INSERT INTO tblMemberLogin
          ( 
            UserID,
            LoginName,
            LoginPassword
          ) 
     VALUES 
          ( 
            @GUID,
            @LoginName,                 
            @LoginPassword              
          ) 

    RETURN @GUID
END
GO
```

However when I execute it I get the following error:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Procedure db_SignupAddLogin, Line 34
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int
```

I cannot quite workout why as i am not referencing an int anywhere.

My Schema for tblMemberLogin looks like this:

UserID(PK,uniqueidentifier,notnull)
LoginName(nchar(15),not null)
LoginPassword(nchar(15),not null)

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RETURN` can only be used with an `int`. You can simply use a `SELECT` query to retrieve the value of variable `@GUID`.

Reference: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998(v=sql.110).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

get rid of `RETURN @GUID` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, stored procedures may only return integer values. [SQL Server RETURN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

If you want to return data from a stored procedure other than an integer, you can use an output parameter: [Returning Data from Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx)

You declare the output parameter along with your input parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CREATE PROCEDURE db_SignupAddLogin 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @LoginName VARCHAR(15), 
    @LoginPassword VARCHAR(15),
    @NewGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @NewGuid = NEWID();

    -- rest of procedure
END
```

And then use the output parameter:

```
DECLARE @NewLoginGuidFromSP UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
EXECUTE db_SignupAddLogin 'Username', 'password', @NewGuid = @NewLoginGuidFromSP OUTPUT;
```